# drawing graphics on Google Charts

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

So i'm working with Google Charts to show some stock data and this is the graph that i have generated (candlestick chart) with the data :

[image: current graph]

My Requirment is like that of below . After some conditions are set , i should be able to bring up these arrows / lines as indicators .

[image: graph required]

Is this possible ? If so , could you please link me to some tutorials or the like ?

Thanks ! :D

Comment: Hi @Shrayas - did you find a solution? I am looking to do the same :)

Comment: Hi @rassom , i didn't find a solution .. I reverted to using [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) . If you want something else .. you can find another question of mine [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426595/charts-for-stock-analysis-applications)