# Charts for stock analysis applications

Tags: jquery, charts, stock

I'm trying to build a stock analysis application and it uses 3 kinds of charts

- Area Charts
- Candlestick Charts
- Combination Charts

Currently i am doing this by using JQuery & Google charts and as u can see below its pretty awesome:

[image: Charts]

But now , i was annotations on these charts . I've put up another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411403/drawing-graphics-on-google-charts) here on StackOverflow asking if something can be annotated on Google charts .

But here , i'm asking if there are any other charts that i can use which supports these 3 types of charts **AND** allows me to annotate (draw shapes at positions) on them.

please help :( I have to deliver this in a week !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would really recommend [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). They are free for open source project bur requires a license if you use it in a commercial project. They even have a library dedicated to stocking charts, called [HighStock](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock).

If you want a free library, my recommendation is [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/). However, it does not come with as many different chart types as HighCharts.

Comment: This is what I would recommend too, very flexible with little effort, extremely smooth implementation with HighCharts/Stock one for an outstanding result.

Comment: @alexn, HighCharts looks awesome ! Its working fine :) THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use jQPlot

http://www.jqplot.com/

Comment: We tried using jQPlot but i dont think i can draw geometric shapes on it and stuff. And getting the 3rd kind of chart was tough

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a server side language there is plenty of libraries that you can use and draw images and of course it can be a chart, also there are some Libraries specifically for drawing Charts.

But here are some really good JavaScript chart Solutions

[HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)  Offer a free licence for non-commercial use, based on jQuery
[GRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) MIT Licence , based on the famous raphael library
[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) With less interaction but still free
[JSCharts](http://www.jscharts.com/) A non-free alternative

The Good point about JS is that it can be interactive.