# Adding flags dynamically giving problems , HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, typeerror

So i asked a couple of days ago [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426595/charts-for-stock-analysis-applications) as to which charts one can use for Stock based applications and i finally settled with [HighCharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) Simply because its so awesome.

Now my chart renders this way and it is as expected.

[image: Candlestick chart]

The next step for me is to place flags on them . Which i am able to do while creating the chart itself and it renders like this:

[image: Candlestick with flag]

```
// some code here
series: [{
                        id: "dataSeries",
                        name: "datadata",
                        type: "candlestick",
                        data: items
                    },{
                         id: "flagSeries",
                         name: "flagflag",
                         type: "flags",
                         data: [{
                             x: 1301651400000,
                             title: 'B',
                             text: 'Shape: "circlepin"'
                         }]
                    }]
// some code here
```

But when i try to do the same dynamically as directed [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3ZdBd/) , i get an error that says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shift' of undefined`

```
//some code here
series: [{
                        id: "dataSeries",
                        name: "datadata",
                        type: "candlestick",
                        data: items
                    },{
                         id: "flagSeries",
                         name: "flagflag",
                         type: "flags",
                         data: []
                    }]
//some code here
$('button').click(function(){
var ser = chart.get("flagSeries");
                console.log(ser);
                ser.addPoint({
                    x: 1301672700000,
                    title: 'C',
                    text: 'Shape: "circlepin"'
                });
});
//some code here
```

How come it works there but not when i try it ? :(

Comment: when are you getting the error ? onClick or onLoad ? maybe you add point to wrong/non-exisiting series ? http://jsfiddle.net/CAKQH/5/ - dynamic addPoint() works ...

Comment: i get the error when i click on the button . The thing is , the code that is found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZdBd/) when put on my local machine , gives that error also . 

i dont understand how it can work online but not on a local machine :(

Comment: do you have same version of HighCharts as on site (ie: most fresh)?

Comment: your code from [here][http://jsfiddle.net/3ZdBd/] **does not work** in none of my browsers. FF / Chr / Op - just graph, and when you click, nothing chages. IE9 - weird button, which does nothing, and no graph.

Comment: It seems to be working really fine for me , IE , not tested but FF / Chrome it works !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3528/discussion-between-shrayas-and-c69)

Comment: If a solution was reached, it would be nice if it were included here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great thanks owed to @c69 who helped me on this .

Apparantly the version they were giving out for download wasn't the one they were using on jsFiddle .

Also i was trying to use the getData function that gave me the problems (because of a bug in the highcharts.js) . But later we understood and we started using the addPoint method instead .

Now it works :D

```
var entry_servlet = 'SOMESERVLET'

    $.getJSON(entry_servlet, function(ret_data) {

        $.each(ret_data, function(key, val) {

            var dat = ret_data[key].date;
            var tim = ret_data[key].time;

            var o = ret_data[key].o;
            var h = ret_data[key].h;
            var l = ret_data[key].l;
            var c = ret_data[key].c;



            datArr = dat.split('/');
            timArr = tim.split(':');

            var UTCthing;


            UTCthing = Date.UTC(datArr[2],datArr[0]-1,datArr[1],timArr[0],timArr[1],timArr[2]);



            window.buck_chart.series[1].addPoint(
                    { 

                            name:'title',
                            title: "B", 
                            x: UTCthing,
                            color: '#009f3c',
                           text: "Price:  " + o + " time:  " + tim                                              
                    },true,false);  

    });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer but i wish it were congruent with the sample in your question (hand-coded data rather than an ajax get).. would it be too much to ask that you make a working fiddle with flags (as the add flag one you posted is broken for me)? I'm trying to make this work as well but these samples aren't really doin it

Comment: Hey @Amalgovinus, Will do this soon and post back :) Could you link me to a sample JSON of your data then i can get it up and running for u

Comment: Thank you so much. Here are four datetime / value pairs: [[Date.UTC(2012,01,1,0), 6], [Date.UTC(2012,01,1,1), 0], [Date.UTC(2012,01,1,2), 13],  [Date.UTC(2012,01,1,3), 14]]