# Creating image with stock plot using PHP

Tags: php, image, charts

How can I create image with stock plot (like in image below) using PHP? I found jpCharts, but it displays only numbers on X axis and I want display dates.

[image: stock plot example]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Charts for stock analysis applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426595/charts-for-stock-analysis-applications)

Comment: I this topic, each solution applies interactive graphs (uses jQuery or pure JavaScript). I want to create static image with graph using PHP.